# Настройка свича с под debian

Tags: свич, debian

Была винда, на свичи заходил через putty, сейчас стоит debian с иксами, как мне зайти в консоль свича чтоб его настроить? в google был, но то ли лыжи не едут, то ли ......

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На свитчах по дефолту телнет включен, через com порт нужно подкл. minicom

Answer (score 0):

А что за свичи, и как именно через putty? Насколько понимаю там есть три варианта: ssh, telnet и консоль RS-232. Один из относительно простых способов поставить putty по линукс, под Убунту такой есть, думаю и под debian тоже.Если ssh или telnet , то можно без "костылей" , просто ввести в терминале telnet IP-адрес свича (для наглядности telnet 192.168.0.1). SSH - ssh 192.168.0.1 -l login ..

Comment: ну это да) там на консоль свича нада зайти через ком порт, телнет на них еще не настроен, нулевые свичи.тоесть с терминала на свич по ком порту не зайти? только путти ставить?

Comment: Да можно с терминала войти, настроить вывод в одну из консолей. Только мне проще было  путти поставить с центра приложений и через него на com-port бегать. Т.к com-port в ноуте не на матери, а через доп.устройство.

Answer (score 0):

Да можно и патти поставить - под Линух он так же имеется - сам периодически пользуюсь.